# Pyspark - writing dataframe to csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a pyspark dataframe into a csv file but the problem I am facing here is datetype fields are converted to IntergerType.

**`Spark version : 2.0.0`**

**Code:**

```
  df.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite")\
 .option("dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").option("escape", "\\").option("header", "true").save(temp_csv_file)  


**Dataframe:**

Please note Date_1 field

+---------+-----+----+----------+------------+---------+
|Store_seq|Store|Dept|    Date_1|Weekly_Sales|IsHoliday|
+---------+-----+----+----------+------------+---------+
|   273048|   28|  49|2010-03-05|    16845.12|    FALSE|
|   323620|   34|  24|2010-06-25|     2123.00|    FALSE|
|   318053|   33|  60|2012-01-20|      176.00|    FALSE|
|   149167|   16|   9|2010-02-12|    11518.21|     TRUE|
|   292767|   30|  92|2011-07-08|    47044.41|    FALSE|
+---------+-----+----+----------+------------+---------+

**csv file:**

+---------+-----+----+------+------------+---------+
|Store_seq|Store|Dept|Date_1|Weekly_Sales|IsHoliday|
+---------+-----+----+------+------------+---------+
|   273048|   28|  49| 14673|    16845.12|    false|
|   323620|   34|  24| 14785|      2123.0|    false|
|   318053|   33|  60| 15359|       176.0|    false|
|   149167|   16|   9| 14652|    11518.21|     true|
|   292767|   30|  92| 15163|    47044.41|    false|
+---------+-----+----+------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: what do you want then? can we see samples of what it is now and how you want it?

Comment: I have edited my oriiginal post. I want to preserve the same datatypes in csv file as well i.e. Write the dataframe as is in csv without any changes.

Comment: can you share the schema of df before you write to csv?

Comment: @Ramesh Thanks for showing me a direction to proceed but getting an error as ** 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'schema'**  for the below code df.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite").\
                    option("dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").option("escape", "\\").schema(tmp_schema).save(temp_csv_file)

Comment: I just wanted you to share the temp_schema . specially the datatype of Date_1 column

Comment: @RameshMaharjan StructType(List(StructField(Store_seq,DecimalType(10,0),true),StructField(Store,DecimalType(10,0),true),StructField(Dept,DecimalType(10,0),true),StructField(Date_1,DateType,true),StructField(Weekly_Sales,DecimalType(18,2),true),StructField(IsHoliday,StringType,true)))

Comment: I couldn't replicate as its working for me. So wait for somebody to help you out

Comment: I also looked into this issue with Spark 2.3 version.. date format working fine with me.. I was too not able to replicate the issue.